# Gradient of a partial differential matrix

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, gradient-descent

$X$ is a $2$ $\times$ $2$ matrix, $W$ is a $2$ $\times$ $3$ matrix, and $Y=XW$,as we know,$Y$ is a $2$ $\times$ $3$ matrix.Now,Set $L$ is a scalar,and the gradient
$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}=$
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{11}} & \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{12}} & \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{13}} \\
    \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{21}} & \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{22}} & \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{23}} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and by the chain rule,we know that:$\frac{\partial L}{\partial X}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}$,$\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial W}$,please show the gradient of $\frac{\partial L}{\partial X}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}W^{T}$

So in fact,i have to prove  $W^T=\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}$, however,the size of $X$ and $Y$ are not the same,it means the number of the element in $X$ and $Y$ are not the same either,in this situation, how to calculate the $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}$ ?

Comment: What exactly is $L$? It is unclear how you could have the matrix you wrote for $\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{Y}}$.

Comment: The question didn't say what exactly is $L$ either,just say it is a scalar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the relationship $Y=XW$ and the gradient wrt $Y$ of some function, i.e. $$G=\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}$$
you must find the gradient wrt $X$.

Rather than using the chain rule, simply expand the differential of the function and then perform a change of variable to obtain the desired result
$$\eqalign{
  dL &= G:dY \cr
  &= G:dX\,W \cr
  &= GW^T:dX \cr
\frac{\partial L}{\partial X} &= GW^T \cr
}$$
where colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$